# Chronological order for Conjuring Universe movies?

Tags: suggested-order, the-conjuring-universe, annabelle

The 2013 movie **The Conjuring** was the one which started the franchise, but it's not the first movie if we consider the *chronology*. Afterwards, there have been multiple sequels and spin-offs that do not match the linear timeline order and the viewer might get confused (For example, Annabelle the doll is already with the Warrens in the first Conjuring movie, but how Warrens got her was explained in movies that came later).

What is the order that someone should watch these movies to get the correct idea of the timeline?

Answer (score 5):

So far, there are **9** official movies in [the *Conjuring Universe*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Conjuring_Universe).

In the following list, the first year in **bold** is the year that the events of each movie takes place, while the second year in brackets is the year that each movie was released.

**1952:**  The Nun (2018)
**1955:**  Annabelle: Creation (2017)
**1956:**  The Nun 2 (2023)
**1967:**  Annabelle (2014)
**1971:**  The Conjuring (2013)
**1972:**  Annabelle Comes Home (2019)
**1973:**  The Curse of La Llorona (2019)
**1977:**  The Conjuring 2 (2016)
**1981:**  The Conjuring: The Devil Made Me Do It (2021)